# Html method get xml contents

Tags: html, xml, methods, get

this is xml page
http://xSSHplusx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml

I need to perform an html get (don't have any server-side code available due to free host)
to get the ls:islive true/false response

```
    if(.ls:isLive=='true'){
    player.load('SSHplus');
    }
    else{
    player.load('SaveStateHeroes');
    }
```

and I know I'd use
        action="http://channel.api.livestream.com/1.0/livestatus?channel=savestateheroes" method="get"

I don't know how to pull the data and check the contents using an if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the complete code i guess you are looking for

```
   // Load the xml file using ajax 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xSSHplusx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            // Parse the xml file and get data
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                $xml = $(xmlDoc);

        if($xml.find('ls\\\\:isLive,isLive').text()=='true'){
             player.load('SSHplus');
             }
             else{
                player.load('SaveStateHeroes');
               }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked, here's a gist of what I've got so far.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5b47bbc4268bfdfb6077

since it was too long to fit here

and I'm not sure whether I'd need to use setinterval to loop in order to check whether the xml has changed? or whether it would detect the change regardless?

Comment: I can't make it loop, I need to keep retrieving and parsing the xml to retrieve the status update from false to true, and there's no way I can actively test this without a loop to see if it would even work

Comment: if you want to continuously check server for the changes then you can set this code inside a setInterval() method. more.http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Okay, thanks for that I got it to loop. Though now I'm getting the following error " XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{96ee2a7e-4b5a-4c45-99ff-e127b83c516b} Line Number 1, Column 1: "

Comment: you get this error in mozilla, do u tested it on chrome, please elaborate the problem.

Comment: I cannot use the method given with my current host, there's a json alternative I believe I can use, but I could use your help fixing if you could?

         $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xsshplusx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.json?callback=livestatus",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xml) {

        jQuery.parseJSON('{isLive:false,true}');

        if  .text()=='true'){
             player.load('SSHplus');
             }
             else{
                player.load('SaveStateHeroes');
               }
        }
    });